# CPU: 13 PID: 15452 Comm: ssd_blk/0 Tainted: G B I E 3.19.0+ #1

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, block-device, dmesg

I developed a module which works as an emulator for a block device. When I write into the block device, I get this in dmesg and the module crashes. I cannot get any hint about what is going on?

```
[82013.054224] CPU: 9 PID: 15452 Comm: my_blk/0 Tainted: G    B     I E  3.19.0+ #1
[82013.054226] Hardware name: Dell Inc. PowerEdge R730xd/0599V5, BIOS 1.0.4 08/28/2014
[82013.054229]  ffffffff81aa8fb8 ffff881fe1613778 ffffffff817a7f98 0000000000000000
[82013.054234]  0000000000000009 ffff881fe16137a8 ffffffff813c45b5 ffff880030243600
[82013.054239]  ffff881fe0a4c798 ffff883feb3ced00 ffff881fe00c3900 ffff881fe16137b8
[82013.054244] Call Trace:
[82013.054251]  [<ffffffff817a7f98>] dump_stack+0x4f/0x7b
[82013.054257]  [<ffffffff813c45b5>] check_preemption_disabled+0xf5/0x110
[82013.054262]  [<ffffffff813c4607>] debug_smp_processor_id+0x17/0x20
[82013.054276]  [<ffffffffc03599dd>] megasas_build_io_fusion+0x54d/0x5a0 [megaraid_sas]
[82013.054287]  [<ffffffffc0359af1>] megasas_build_and_issue_cmd_fusion+0x71/0x110 [megaraid_sas]
[82013.054296]  [<ffffffffc034cf35>] megasas_queue_command+0x145/0x1b0 [megaraid_sas]
[82013.054301]  [<ffffffff8154ae03>] scsi_dispatch_cmd+0x103/0x370
[82013.054306]  [<ffffffff8154dcbf>] scsi_request_fn+0x4af/0x6c0
[82013.054311]  [<ffffffff81374177>] __blk_run_queue+0x37/0x50
[82013.054315]  [<ffffffff81374dd1>] queue_unplugged+0x41/0xf0
[82013.054320]  [<ffffffff8137a042>] blk_flush_plug_list+0x1d2/0x210
[82013.054325]  [<ffffffff8137a098>] blk_finish_plug+0x18/0x50
[82013.054331]  [<ffffffff8127e54b>] ext4_writepages+0x55b/0xd10
[82013.054336]  [<ffffffff812144ad>] ? __mnt_drop_write+0x2d/0x50
[82013.054342]  [<ffffffff8109d624>] ? finish_task_switch+0x64/0x110
[82013.054348]  [<ffffffff81187ea0>] do_writepages+0x20/0x40
[82013.054352]  [<ffffffff8117c1a9>] __filemap_fdatawrite_range+0x59/0x60
[82013.054356]  [<ffffffff8117c1e7>] filemap_write_and_wait_range+0x37/0x80
[82013.054360]  [<ffffffff8127376a>] ext4_sync_file+0x12a/0x390
///// calling some functions in my_blk
[82013.054397]  [<ffffffff81097b19>] kthread+0xc9/0xe0
[82013.054402]  [<ffffffff81097a50>] ? flush_kthread_worker+0x90/0x90
[82013.054407]  [<ffffffff817af7bc>] ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
[82013.054412]  [<ffffffff81097a50>] ? flush_kthread_worker+0x90/0x90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens when I set `CONFIG_PREEMPT=y` in my kernel configurations. To solve the problem on linux 3.19.0, I had to apply following patch, which change `smp_processor_id()` to `raw_smp_processor_id()` in `drivers/scsi/megaraid/megaraid_sas_io_fusion.c`. The patch is in the following link:

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.scsi/100408

Answer (score 0):

The first line: **CPU: 9 PID: 15452 Comm: my_blk/0 Tainted: G    B**

From here: https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3582750

Tainted flag **B** means: A process has been found in a Bad page state, indicating a corruption of the virtual memory subsystem, possibly caused by malfunctioning RAM or cache memory.

This implies one possible reason is your writing to the block device may addressed to the wrong space in the VM, and corrupted the VM subsystem somehow.